# Cordova App -- why does iOS returned user agent change each time

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a Cordova app which the server needs to validate the cookie information sent back.  Part of the check is to validate the useragent.  However on iOS I'm seeing the user agent contains a numbered string at the end that always changes with each request.  Can anyone tell me what is the intended purpose of the numbered string?  Can I just remove it server side?

Here are examples of agent information I'm getting:

- agent:mozilla/5.0 (iphone; cpu iphone os 9_2 like mac os x)
  applewebkit/601.1.46 (khtml, like gecko) mobile/13c75 (384496528)
- agent:mozilla/5.0 (iphone; cpu iphone os 9_2 like mac os x)
  applewebkit/601.1.46 (khtml, like gecko) mobile/13c75 (358004416)

Answer (score 0):

That string can be 'Build Date:'. You don't need that string for the server storage, for the user agent you only need the forward part mostly

Reference: http://www.useragentstring.com/index.php, if you put your request in the above site it will give you information about the parts of user-agent string

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not a build date as suggested by [www.useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com).
From the Cordova devs, this is a remnant of an old “Cordova Bridge” implementation that used XmlHttpRequest for bridging to native. The token is generated on each app session, and is used for the bridge as an auth token.

That bridge has been removed in cordova-ios-4.x, but looks like that auth token in the user agent was not removed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from the Cordova-iOS lead:

> Unfortunately this is a remnant of an old “Cordova Bridge” implementation that used XmlHttpRequest for bridging to native. The token is generated on each app session, and is used for the bridge as an auth token.
>   That bridge has been removed in cordova-ios-4.x, but looks like that auth token in the user agent was not removed.